# Creating NEW files and folders

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

```
Sub Test()
Dim myDir As String
Dim Folder1 As String

StartDate = DateValue("2-Nov-2014")
NumberOfDays = 1

For N = 0 To NumberOfDays - 1
Folder1 = UCase(Format(StartDate + N, "MMM YYYY"))
Folder2 = Format(StartDate + N, "DD MMM YYYY")
If Dir("C:\GRANDVARIATIONS\FILES\" & Folder1, vbDirectory) = "" Then
MkDir "C:\GRANDVARIATIONS\FILES\" & Folder1
End If
If Dir("C:\GRANDVARIATIONS\FILES\" & Folder1 & "\" & Folder2, vbDirectory) = "" Then
MkDir "C:\GRANDVARIATIONS\FILES\" & Folder1 & "\" & Folder2
End If




On Error Resume Next
Set oDoc = GetObject(sDocPath)
Set oWord = oDoc.Parent
If Err <> 0 Then
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
End If

oDoc.SaveAs ("C:\GRANDVARIATIONS\FILES\" & Folder1 & "\" & Folder2 & "\ANSWERS.Docx")
oDoc.Close

Next N
End Sub
```

In a "FILES" folder there is already "1-Nov-2014" and by using the above code I am able to create another file named "2-Nov-2014".

But, while creating file named "3-Nov-2014", again I have to change "StartDate = DateValue("2-Nov-2014")" to "StartDate = DateValue("3-Nov-2014")".

Is there a way so that I won't have to change that value every time I want to create a new file?

Comment: If you don't supply the date, how's it supposed to know which date you'd like to use? Is it supposed to be "today's" date or something?

Comment: Well , it's not about date . I just want to create next file in chronological order. Lets say if in a folder called "FILES" there is already a file named "1-nov-2014" then i want the code to search that folder and create a new file named "2-nov-2014" with a word document inside it.

Comment: OK, good to know - you should edit that info into your question.  Anyhow, so you need to iterate over the folders, determine which is the newest one, and then set the variable to that date.  What have you tried so far?  Where are you getting stuck exactly?

Comment: Over here if a file named 3-nov-2014 is needed then i need to edit "StartDate = DateValue("2-Nov-2014"): to "StartDate = DateValue("3-Nov-2014"): .

Comment: "iterate over the folders, determine which is the newest one, and then set the variable to that date". If this could be done in another way then that would also be most appreciated.

Comment: "If this could be done in another way then that would also be most appreciated" I'm not sure what you're asking here?  We're not a script writing service, you need to tell us what you've tried so far, and where you're getting stuck (specifically).

Comment: In a "FILES" folder there is already "1-Nov-2014" and by using the above code I am able to create another file named "2-Nov-2014".

But, while creating file named "3-Nov-2014", again I have to change "StartDate = DateValue("2-Nov-2014")" to "StartDate = DateValue("3-Nov-2014")".

Is there a way so that I won't have to change that value every time I want to create a new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Test()
Dim myDir As String
Dim Folder1 As String
Dim rRange1 As Range

Set rRange1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D3")

StartDate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D3")
NumberOfDays = 1

For N = 0 To NumberOfDays - 1
    Folder1 = UCase(Format(StartDate, "MMM YYYY"))
    Folder2 = Format(StartDate + N, "DD MMM YYYY")
    If Dir("C:\GRANDVARIATIONS\FILES\" & Folder1, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir "C:\GRANDVARIATIONS\FILES\" & Folder1
    End If
    If Dir("C:\GRANDVARIATIONS\FILES\" & Folder1 & "\" & Folder2, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir "C:\GRANDVARIATIONS\FILES\" & Folder1 & "\" & Folder2
    End If




On Error Resume Next
    Set oDoc = GetObject(sDocPath)
    Set oWord = oDoc.Parent
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
    End If

oDoc.SaveAs ("C:\GRANDVARIATIONS\FILES\" & Folder1 & "\" & Folder2 & "\ANSWERS.Docx")
oDoc.Close

Next N
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use todays date to create the folders, change

```
StartDate = DateValue("2-Nov-2014")
```

to:

```
StartDate = DateValue(date)
```

If you want something else, then I'm afraid your question is unclear and needs more clarity.